# C# Query Group to List

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, unique

I've tried to figure this out for over two days now but I can't get it to work. I have two entities: Film (movie) and Voorstelling (Screening). A Film has multiple voorstelling and a voorstelling has only one film.

Now I'm trying to select all films that have a voorstelling with a date in the future and return those as a List. So I wrote the query that is below, but since it has a Group by it's returning a IGrouping which I don't know how to convert to a List. I only want to have every Film listed Once (Right now It'll return multiple entries because there might be more then one Voorstelling for that Film.)

The Query I'm using right now is:

```
var films = from f in dbContext.Films
            join v in dbContext.Voorstellingen on f equals v.Film
            where v.Start >= DateTime.Now
            group f by v.Id into grouping
            select grouping;
```

**So long question short:** How do I make sure the grouping only contains every Film once (unique).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Extension Methods:

```
var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
var films = dbContext.Films.Where(f => f.Voorstellingen.Any(s => s.Start >= currentTime)).ToList();
```

Comment: This answer should work only if Films have Voorstellingen as a property. But from the original query they seem to be separated and not connected as properties.

Comment: @VaskoPoposki OP is using Entity Framework (hence the use of `dbContext`), which would require him to have a `Voorstellingen` property in order to properly have the relationship that he mentioned between the 2 tables.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I was indeed using the Entity Framework and Films has Voorstellingen as a property.